# Making fifo in C

Tags: c, file-io, fifo

I have two problems with my code.

First problem is that once I create a fifo, I don't know how to add a condition in the code so in future running, if the fifo exists - then just don't create it. Tried to google, "access" didn't work (it just stucked on there and didn't continue).

My second problem is, that the code is stuck in the "open("MyFifo..." line, even if it's the first time after I created the fifo (meaning I just created the fifo, mkfifo succeed, and I reach open() line - it's stuck there).

```
//create new fifo
if(mkfifo("myFifo",0666)<0)
{
    perror("fifo creation failed.");
    exit(1);
}

//get fifo fd
if((fd=open("myFifo",O_RDONLY))==-1)
{
    perror("failed opening fifo.");
    exit(1);
}
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function call you’re looking for is [`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat). If the file exists, it will fill a `struct stat` with file attributes such as modification time. If the file does not exist, `stat()` will return -1 and `errno` will be set to `EACCESS`.

---

The [`mkfifo` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo) says,

> Opening a FIFO for reading normally blocks until some other process opens the same FIFO for writing, and vice versa.

To get `open()` to stop hanging, start another process that writes to the FIFO first. If the other process opens the FIFO for writing first, the reading program won’t hang at all on `open()`.

Comment: Thanks. Another question: reading from a fifo is blocking either? I mean, if I read an empty fifo, my process will be blocked until someone writes to it? How can I implement "read from fifo when someone has written to it"?

Comment: `read` on a FIFO blocks until another process `write`s to it. See [Beej’s Guide to Unix IPC](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/fifos.html).

Comment: `EACCESS` is not the only possible error you'll get from `stat()`; you could get `ENOTDIR` if the name is a pathname and one of the components is a non-existent directory, or `ELOOP`, or ...  It is not necessarily infeasible to simply try creating the FIFO, and only complain if the error is not `EEXIST`.  Then you know the name exists; you simply need to use `stat()` to validate whether it is a FIFO after all (`S_ISFIFO()`).